# Create a vector function to clean address data for Houston Crime Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, ggmap

There are good tutorials for mapping Houston Crime data, but no easy examples of how to clean the raw data provided from HPD. 
https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Crime-in-Downtown-Houston,-Texas-:-Combining-ggplot2-and-Google-Maps

```
d <- structure(list(BlockRange = c("5400-5499", "3700-3799", "2200-2299", 
    "1000-1099", "1200-1299", "UNK", "1900-1999", "500-599", "1200-1299"
    ), StreetName = c("BELL", "BELL", "BELL", "BELL", "BELL", "BELL", 
    "BELL", "BELL", "BELL"), Date = c("4/28/2015", "4/11/2015", "4/26/2015", 
    "4/9/2015", "4/9/2015", "4/21/2015", "4/26/2015", "4/26/2015", 
    "4/17/2015")), row.names = c(60L, 75L, 88L, 4972L, 4990L, 5096L, 
    5098L, 5099L, 5155L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("BlockRange", 
    "StreetName", "Date"))
```

This will return the Lon and Lat:

```
x <- gGeoCode("1950 Bell St, Houston, TX")
#[1]  29.74800 -95.35926
```

However, it needs a function that will geocode an entire database and add columns for Lon and Lat

Example of a selection of the finished data.

```
structure(list(address = c("9650 marlive ln", "4750 telephone rd", 
"5050 wickview ln", "1050 ashland st", "8350 canyon", "9350 rowan ln", 
"2550 southmore blvd", "6350 rupley cir", "5050 georgi ln", "10750 briar forest dr"
), lon = c(-95.4373883, -95.2988769, -95.455864, -95.4033373, 
-95.3779081, -95.5483009, -95.3733977, -95.3156032, -95.4665841, 
-95.565934), lat = c(29.6779015, 29.6917121, 29.5992174, 29.7902425, 
29.6706341, 29.7022336, 29.7198936, 29.6902746, 29.8297359, 29.747596
)), row.names = 82729:82738, class = "data.frame", .Names = c("address", 
"lon", "lat"))
```

Here are the functions for geocoding:

```
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
library(dplyr)
library(gdata)


construct.geocode.url <- function(address, return.call = "json", sensor = "false") {
  root <- "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/"
  u <- paste(root, return.call, "?address=", address, "&sensor=", sensor, sep = "")
  return(URLencode(u))
}

gGeoCode <- function(address,verbose=FALSE) {
  if(verbose) cat(address,"\n")
  u <- construct.geocode.url(address)
  doc <- getURL(u)
  x <- fromJSON(doc,simplify = FALSE)
  if(x$status=="OK") {
    lat <- x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat
    lng <- x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lng
    return(c(lat, lng))
  } else {
    return(c(NA,NA))
  }
}
```

How can we write a function using dplyr or another method that adds another 3 more columns with the output of [address, long, lat]?

i.e..

```
data.frame <- mutate(d, address = ConvertBlockRange(BlockRange) + StreetName, "Houston, TX"), Lon = geocode(address)[0] , lat = geocode(address)[1])
```

This is the blocking point of the question:

```
#function to convert - "2200-2299" to integer 2250.. i.e find the middle of the block.    


    library(stringr)             
    ConvertBlockRange <- function(blockRange){
    m <-   unlist(str_split(d$BlockRange, "-"))
  m2 <- mean(c(as.numeric(m[1]),as.numeric(m[2]))) + .5
  m2
}
```

Comment: Explain the 'mean of block range' call. Instead of writing the pseudo-code, give us the exact output that you would expect with the example.

Comment: What about the address with "UNK" block range? how do you geocode that?

Comment: so the function would have to throw an exception for that.. or round down. Now I'm having trouble converting "2200-2299", but I will have to be robust enough to geocode about 50,000 addresses.. or at least build a dictionary of unique ones because of API limits

Comment: So `d` is what you are starting with the second unnamed data frame is the expected output?

Comment: The d is a sample of the data set for one street.. the second dataframe is an example output of a data.frame after cleaning. That data frame would still be attached to the rest of the data for geo ploting onto a map

Comment: For geocoding, you've got a few (non-R) options that I've had some success with in the past: 1) use QGIS geocoding--they've got a few APIs built in, including Google & a few others. Not recommended if you've got a _lot_ of addresses to geocode as this will take quite some time. 2) Try Smarty Streets. I personally have a free account (with unlimited lookups) because I'm a student. I'd use this if you've got a lot of addresses to geocode.

Comment: The geocoding works fine more or less with the functions that are there, the string manipulation for R is a bit rusty,  and the address cleaning is challenging me.

Comment: for the mean block ranges try: `d$mean <- lapply(strsplit(d$BlockRange, "-"), function(x) round(mean(as.numeric(x))))
`

Comment: By the way, this is not a `ggplot` or `geocode` question. It is primarily a data manipulation problem. You do not have to post all the other functions that you use later in the project. Just ask a targeted question like "how do I find the mean of a character vector of values?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the mean block range by splitting the range and averaging:

e.g.

```
x <- '5400-5499'
mean(as.numeric(strsplit(x, '-')[[1]])) # 5449.5
```

To scale it up, we can use `separate` from the `tidyr` package. This does some cool things like automagically putting the min/max of blockrange into a new column, converting the types from string to numeric (`convert=T, type.convert=as.numeric`). I `filter` out the "UNK" addresses first - you will have to handle them separately.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) 
d %>%
  filter(BlockRange != "UNK") %>%
  # this is a df with blockmin & blockmax
  separate(BlockRange, c("blockmin", "blockmax"), sep = "-", 
           convert=T, type.convert=as.numeric, remove=FALSE) %>%
  # calc average (round down) and address
  mutate(block=floor((blockmin + blockmax)/2),
         address=paste(block, StreetName))

#   BlockRange blockmin blockmax StreetName      Date block   address
# 1  5400-5499     5400     5499       BELL 4/28/2015  5449 5449 BELL
# 2  3700-3799     3700     3799       BELL 4/11/2015  3749 3749 BELL
# 3  2200-2299     2200     2299       BELL 4/26/2015  2249 2249 BELL
# 4  1000-1099     1000     1099       BELL  4/9/2015  1049 1049 BELL
# 5  1200-1299     1200     1299       BELL  4/9/2015  1249 1249 BELL
# 6  1900-1999     1900     1999       BELL 4/26/2015  1949 1949 BELL
# 7    500-599      500      599       BELL 4/26/2015   549  549 BELL
# 8  1200-1299     1200     1299       BELL 4/17/2015  1249 1249 BELL
```

Then you could `%>% group_by(address)` to get unique addresses and geocode (though I'd think about how to restrict maximum number of requests etc here).

With regards to adding your output lat and lon columns all at once, I don't think dplyr does this yet (see [this feature request](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/154)).

If you really want to use the `dplyr` syntax here, your best bet is to change `gGeoCode` so that it is vectorised, e.g.

```
gGeoCode2 <- function (addresses) {
    x <- data.frame(t(sapply(addresses[[1]], gGeoCode)), row.names=NULL)
    names(x) <- c('lat', 'lng')
    x
}

d2 %>%
   select(address) %>%
   gGeoCode2 %>%
   bind_cols(d2, .)
```

but really really I think you should skip the `dplyr` sugar for this particular step and do a manual loop and `cbind` the result, which gives you greater control over request limiting.

Comment: Excellent..Thank You I havn't used R much in the last 18 months, and it looks like tidyr is pretty powerful. I'll have to ready through it.

Comment: dplyr is actually pretty new to me, I still use ddply for everything